# How to programmatically generate tabset-panel in quarto?

Tags: r, quarto

I've provided a small reproducible example below. I would like to generate tabs in quarto for each of the ggplot objects within a named list `plots`. The below quarto document would render the figures in their own 2nd level heading, but not in tabs as expected.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

data <- iris %>% as_tibble()

plots <- data %>%
  group_nest(Species) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  map(., ~ {
    ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point()
  })

```

# Iris Plots 

::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| column: screen
#| fig-width: 12
#| fig-height: 8
#| fig-align: center
#| results: asis

iwalk(plots, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  
  print(.x)
  
  cat('\n\n')
  
})

```

:::
````

The document would correctly render the plots within tabs as expected when the chunk-options (all except results:asis) were removed.

````
# Iris Plots 

::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| results: asis

iwalk(plots, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  
  print(.x)
  
  cat('\n\n')
  
})

```

:::
````

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Now if you want to generate tabsets which would expand the whole width of the screen, wrap the `.panel-tabset` div with the `.column-screen` div.

**Note that, we have to use more `:` for `.column-screen` than that of `.panel-tabset` div. We have used three `:` for `.panel-tabset`, so we have to use four more of the `:` to create div for `column-screen`.**

---

````
---
title: "Panel tabs"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

data <- iris %>% as_tibble()

plots <- data %>%
  group_nest(Species) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  map(., ~ {
    ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point() +
      theme_bw(
        base_size = 18 # to increase the size of the plot elements
      )
  }) 

```

# Iris Plots 

:::: {.column-screen}
::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| results: asis
#| fig-width: 14
#| fig-height: 6

iwalk(plots, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  
  print(.x)
  
  cat('\n\n')
  
})

```

:::
::::
````

---

Now the **panel tabsets** are expanded to the width of the screen.

[image: panel_tab_with_screen_width]

Also Note that, I have increased the size of elements of the plot (e.g. axis.title, axis.text etc.) with `base_size = 18` in plot-theme.

---

### Old Answer

Your first approach would work if you just remove the `column: screen` and `fig-align: center` from the chunk option.

Because these two chunk options are preventing `.panel-tabset` from properly creating the divs for rendering tabsets.

So this works after removing these two chunk option (and you don't need `fig-align: center` since figures in tabsets are by default centered.

---

````
# Iris Plots 

::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| fig-width: 12
#| fig-height: 8
#| results: asis

iwalk(plots, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  
  print(.x)
  
  cat('\n\n')
  
})

```
````

Comment: [R Workflow](https://hbiostat.org/rflow) shows how to use some functions to generate tabs and other Quarto elements.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I would ideally like to be able to adjust the chunk options such as columns: screen, which would produce tabs for the figures that expands the width of the screen.

Comment: @MichaelLuu, see my update.

Comment: Great thank you so much! That did the trick! I've accepted the answer

Comment: @shafee thanks for this! very interesting. i have another list of tables and would like to put it in the margin next to the plot, but still under the tabset. do you have any suggestions for how to do this? i'm trying to use `#| column: margin` but this has to be in a new chunk.

Comment: I would recommend to create a new question with a reprex stating clearly your expected output if your question is not directly a duplicate of existing ones :)