# Programatically generate tabset panels of datatables in Quarto

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown, dt, quarto

This question is similar, but not identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367433/how-to-programmatically-generate-tabset-panel-in-quarto).

Basically, I have a number of tables that I would like to show in tabsets using `DT::datatable()`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how.

The following code works, but I need to manually type all the code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(DT)
```
    
::: {.panel-tabset}

### table no. 1

```{r}
#| results: asis
datatable(mtcars)
```

### table no. 2

```{r}
#| results: asis
datatable(mtcars)
```
:::
````

The following works, but instead of `datatable()` uses a simple markdown table from `pander` which does not give the desired effect.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(pander)
```
    
::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| results: asis

for(i in 1:2) {
  cat(sprintf("\n### table no. %d\n\n", i))
  cat(pander(mtcars))
}
```
:::
````

The following code does not work, and I don't know how to make it work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(DT)
```
    
::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| results: asis

for(i in 1:2) {
  cat(sprintf("\n### table no. %d\n\n", i))
  print(datatable(mtcars))
}
```
:::
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue in the context of RMarkdown. But as it turns out the solution for RMarkdown also works for Quarto.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685631/using-ggplotly-and-dt-from-a-for-loop-in-rmarkdown/62599342#62599342) related to the same issue in RMarkdown [Discalimer: The answer is from me] you could achieve your desired result by first making sure that the javascript dependencies needed for `DT` are included in your document and by wrapping the `datatable` call inside `htmltools::tagList`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(DT)
```
    
```{r, include=FALSE}
# Init Step to make sure that the dependencies are loaded
htmltools::tagList(datatable(mtcars))
```

::: {.panel-tabset}
```{r}
#| results: asis
for(i in 1:2) {
  cat(sprintf("\n### table no. %d\n\n", i))
  print(htmltools::tagList(datatable(mtcars)))
}
```
:::
````

[image]

Comment: Nice! I used to have a weird workaround in Rmarkdown using knitr chunks, but this is so. much. easier.