# How to resolve Quarto version upgrade breaking panel-tabset and pandas.to_html() interaction (1.2->1.3)

Tags: python, markdown, quarto

Rendering the below code chunk with Quarto cli version 1.2 generates 3 tabs labeled a, b and c with a nicely rendered table in each tab. However when I upgrade to version 1.3 all the tables appear in tab a.

Is there a way I should be using panel-tabset differently in version 1.3? Or if this was hacky and never really supported are there any alternative ways quarto can display tabs. I can't find any good alternatives to what I have achieved here in their documentation?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

# Test doc

::: {.panel-tabset}
```{python}
# | output: asis
import pandas as pd
import random
from IPython.display import display, Markdown, Latex
df = pd.DataFrame({"group":["a"]*3 + ["b"]*3 + ["c"]*3,"value":[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(9)]})


for group in df["group"].drop_duplicates():

    display(Markdown(f"\n"))
    display(Markdown(f"## {group}\n"))
    display(Markdown(f"\n"))
    print(df[df["group"]==group].to_html())

```

:::
````

Comment: Next time remember to include the yaml and use ```` with qmd to render the code better as it is pointed out in https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7414#discussioncomment-7576354.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following and reduce the amount of modules imported so you will reduce the probability of having problems in the future:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

# Test doc

::: {.panel-tabset}

```{python}
#| output: asis
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({"group":["a"]*3 + ["b"]*3 + ["c"]*3,
                   "value":[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(9)]})

for group in df["group"].drop_duplicates():

    print(f"## {group}")
    print(df[df["group"]==group].to_html())
    print()
```
:::
````

The sources I used to find the answer where the following:

- Quarto tabsets documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#tabsets
- [How to programmatically generate tabset-panel in quarto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367433/how-to-programmatically-generate-tabset-panel-in-quarto)
- How to create tabset programatically from Python #7414: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7414